# express router matching wrong routes with nested router.use

Tags: node.js, express

I have created some nested routes, so base route is `/api/v1` and then it matches other routes

i.e `/cities` or `services`

Now those routes also have their on sub routes

i.e

```
/api/v1/services
 GET /
 GET /services/:id
```

This is what I have done for this setup

app.js

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

// load routes
require('./loader/routes')(app);
...
```

*loader/routes.js*

```
const router = require('express').Router();

const v1Router = require('../v1/router')(router );

module.exports = (app) => {
  app.use('/api/v1', v1Router);
};
```

At this point routes should match `/api/v1`

*v1/router/index.js*

```
const makeServiceRoutes = require('./ServiceRouter');

module.exports = (router) => {
  router.use('/items', makeItemRoutes(router, ItemController));
  router.use('/cities', makeCityRoutes(router, CityController));
  router.use('/services', makeServiceRoutes(router, ServiceController));
  return router
}
```

At this point routes should match to `api/v1/services`

Now *ServiceRouter.js* does sub routes.

```
module.exports = (router, ServiceController) => {
  router.get('/', ServiceController.getAllServices);
  router.get('/:id', ServiceController.getServiceById);
  return router;
};
```

The problem is

***It is hitting `api/v1/cities/:id` for `/api/v1/services`***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't mount `router` itself. Create and mount a new sub router for `ServiceRouter.js`:

```js
module.exports = (ServiceController) => {
  const router = require('express').Router();
  router.get('/', ServiceController.getAllServices);
  router.get('/:id', ServiceController.getServiceById);
  return router;
};
```